# ios passing a void* into UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, void-pointers

I'm new to Swift. I'm trying to use the method signature in my class:

```
func UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(_ videoPath: String!,
                                   _ completionTarget: AnyObject!,
                                   _ completionSelector: Selector,
                                   _ contextInfo: CMutableVoidPointer)
```

The last argument, contextInfo, is a void * in obj-c.

I get an `NSDictionary` not a subtype of `CMutableVoidPointer` error if I pass a dictionary in Swift. Would appreciate any help with this. I don't know how to pass a `void` * equivalent argument in Swift without getting that error.

Answer (score 9):

Objective C - Void*

Swift - UnsafeMutablePointer

.. Example

// Your call to save video to camera roll

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(yourVideoPath, self, "video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

// Your Completion Handler after video is saved

```
    func video(videoPath: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError, contextInfo info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
// your completion code handled here

}
```

Comment: you get an optional NSError object so it should be NSError?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use `var`, not `let`
var userInfo: NSDictionary = ....
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(..., ..., ..., &userInfo)
```

`CMutableVoidPointer` is `void *`
`CConstVoidPointer` is `const void *`

Comment: That gets rid of the error but wouldn't your code cause a segfault since you're passing in a stack pointer? So if the frame that userInfo is declared in pops a callback with the &userinfo would be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

You can pass a NSDictionary as an UnsafeMutablePointer following a few steps:

1) declare a dictionary as a property of your view controller

```
var userInfo: NSDictionary = [:]
```

2) Second you will need to declare a method to be called when your picker is finished saving your image/video asynchronously:

```
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    print(#function)
    let infoDict = Unmanaged<NSDictionary>
            .fromOpaque(contextInfo)
            .takeUnretainedValue()
        as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
    print("infoDict", infoDict )
}
```

3) You will need to convert your NSDictionary to a UnsafeMutableRawPointer:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    print(#function)
    if let img = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        userInfo = info as NSDictionary
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img,
                                       self,
                                       #selector(image),
                                       UnsafeMutableRawPointer(
                                            Unmanaged
                                            .passUnretained(userInfo)
                                            .toOpaque()))
    }
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```